# Uncatchable ConstraintViolationException (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

like in topic.
I can't handle that exception.

You can see the code here:
https://github.com/ApproxTeam/AntColosseumIIServer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/approxteam/antcolosseumserver/gamelogic/interfaces/beans/WebSocketRegisterer.java

All i want to achieve is catch exception instead of ruin all method that invoke that bean.

All stacktrace: http://wklejto.pl/txt299134

I trying to catch Throwable, Exception, PersistenceException, HibernateException, ConstaintVolablablaException but all doesn't works.

What is wrong?

I'm using Hibernate 5+ and MySQL as database.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work ?

Comment: Catch clause wasnt working, never reach them and method just fail

Comment: Please put the code and the exception stacktrace inside your question. Questions should be self-contained and not rely on external links for important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answer:

I added a

```
    entityManager.flush();
```

to save method and it works

```
public void save(Object o) throws Exception {
    entityManager.persist(o);
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the stack

```
 Duplicate entry 'E-mail' for key 'UK_jxn5vjjm6ho216fwddjg10uce'
```

There is unique key constraint on `Email` column.

So, either remove the constraint from  your table to allow duplicate `Email` or change `Email` value while saving it.

Comment: It's not what i want to achieve. I want to have unique emails and ability to catch exception if there is duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Please check your MySQL driver version, there were some bugs in database that result in problem with catching exceptions, see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68831.

Comment: From phpmyadmin:  MariaDB 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 - Raspbian 9.0

Comment: I will try to change mysqlconnector to mariadbconnector - maybe it will works? Thanks for hint

Comment: Nope, it's not working